# Правильно задать layout_width

Tags: android-sdk, android, google-maps-api

Доброго времени суток. У меня проблема. Заказчик сделал кнопки в фотошопе, поэтому я их ставлю в бекгроунд как изображение и получается проблема с разрешением на девайсах. как решить эту проблему не знаю. Могу сделать какой-то свой xml и там задать какой-то градиент, но это будут не кнопки заказчика. Нужно запилить именно его кнопки.
вот я делал таким образом:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFilters"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/filters"
            android:onClick="filters_onclick"
            android:text="Мои Фильтры" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCabinet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnFilters"
            android:background="@drawable/cabinet"
            android:onClick="cabinet_onclick"
            android:text="Мой Кабинет" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/settings"
            android:onClick="settings_onclick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/refresh"
            android:onClick="refresh_onclick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnRefresh"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:onClick="back_onclick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnBack"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/next"
            android:onClick="next_onclick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/plus"
            android:onClick="plus_onclick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnPlus"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/minus"
            android:onClick="settings_onclick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnMinus"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/go"
            android:onClick="go_onclick" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

результат в ide:
[image]

результат на девайсе логичен

[image]

**Проблема была решена.** Вместо Button поставил ImageButton и сразу разрешение стало нормальным. А почему так, я не понимаю. я отключил стандартны кнопки зума и локации. Осталось как-то функцию локации и зума дать моим кастомным кнопкам. а как это делать в google map api v2 не знаю

[image]

Comment: я так понимаю у вас картинки лежать просто в папке drawable. попробуйте запихать их в mdpi, и как вам посоветовали ниже нарисуйте для разных разрешений :)

Comment: запихнул в mdpi и вместо button использовал ImageButton и помогло. спасибо. но не до конца понял принцип работы совместимости разных экранов. понял только что для каждой папки(mdpi, ldpi, hdpi,..) нужно делать отдельно с разным разрешением по возрастанию начиная с hdpi и заканчивая xxhdpi

Answer (score 2):

В качестве фона кнопки используйте nine-patch изображение (.9.png). Ну а сами иконки на кнопках необходимо заготовить в нескольких вариантах для различных плотностей экрана (директории drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi и т.д.), указывая их, например, для `ImageButton`.

Comment: я запутался в этих разрешениях. у меня девайс имеет разрешение 480х800 и я специально в фотошопе сделал 480х800, затем сохранил как отдельные компоненты эти кнопки, но они все-равно не подходят в какую бы папку drawable я их не помещал. у меня htc desire x даже не знаю к какой категории он относится ldpi, mdpi, hdpi. вообще читал документацию, вроде английский знаю, но почему-то непонятен принцип работы.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно в данном случае попросить заказчика нарисовать для каждого разрешения нужный дизайн